# Maven Project local git repository wont work

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I am new to maven projects in eclipse and Git.
I have created a maven project. It works fine until I add a Local git repository to add my project on remote github.
My rest api works no more throwing no content error( No resources found).

Here is my code:

**API:**

```
package com.gtu.project.quickpay;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.gtu.project.quickpay.services.AccountService;
import com.gtu.project.quickpay.services.CustomerService;
import com.gtu.project.quickpay.services.UserService;
import com.gtu.project.quickpay.models.Account;
import com.gtu.project.quickpay.models.Customer;
import com.gtu.project.quickpay.models.User;

@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

//get all accounts
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Account> getAllAccounts() {
    return AccountService.getAllAccounts();
}

@Path("createAccount")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Account createAccount(Account acc){
    Account account =  AccountService.createAccount(acc.getBalance(),acc.getPin(),acc.getCardId());
    return account;
}


@Path("createCustomer")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Customer createCustomer(Customer cus){
    Customer customer =  CustomerService.createCustomer(cus.getFirstName(),cus.getMiddleName(),
            cus.getLastName(),cus.getGender(),cus.getAddress(),cus.getPincode(),cus.getPhone(),
            cus.getEmail(),cus.getAccountId());
    return customer;
}

@Path("createUser")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User createUser(User us){
    User user =  UserService.createUser(us.getCustomerId(),us.getPassword());
    return user;
}
}
```

**main.js**

```
$(function(){
console.log("Jquery called");
$('#add-account').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var middleName = $("#middleName").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
    var gender = $("input:radio[name=gender]").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var pincode = $("#pincode").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var balance = $("#balance").val();
    var pin = $("#pin").val();
    var cardId = $("#cardId").val();
    alert("Password:"+password);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8081/quickpay/webapi/myresource/createAccount",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "balance":balance,
            "pin": pin,
            "cardId": cardId
        }), 
        dataType: "json",
        success:function (successResponse,textStatus,jqXHR) {
            var accountId = successResponse.accountId ;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8081/quickpay/webapi/myresource/createCustomer",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "firstName":firstName,
                    "middleName":middleName,
                    "lastName":lastName,
                    "gender":gender,
                    "address":address,
                    "pincode":pincode,
                    "phone":phone,
                    "email":email,
                    "accountId":accountId
                }), 
                dataType: "json",
                success:function (successResponse1,textStatus,jqXHR) {
                    var customerId = successResponse1.customerId;
                    var gender = successResponse1.gender;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost:8081/quickpay/webapi/myresource/createUser",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            "customerId":customerId,
                            "password":password
                        }), 
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function (successResponse2,textStatus,jqXHR) {
                            if(textStatus == "success"){
                                alert("Registered:"+textStatus+"\n Use Following credentials to login:\n"
                                        +"Username:"+customerId+"Password:"+password+"\nGender is:"+gender);
                            }
                            else{
                                alert("Status:"+textStatus);
                            }

                            location.reload();
                        },
                        error: function (errorResponse2) {
                            console.log(errorResponse2);
                            alert(errorResponse2);
                        }
                    }); 
                },
                error: function (errorResponse1) {
                    console.log(errorResponse1);
                    alert(errorResponse1);
                }
            }); 
        },
        error: function (errorResponse) {
            console.log(errorResponse);
            alert("Account api");
        }
    });
});
});
```

**When I click Register button nothing happens except alert box that I put for debugging.**

**For this url in POSTMAN:**

http://localhost:8081/quickpay/webapi/myresource/createAccount

**Throws Error:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.62 - Error report</title>
    <style>
        <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 404 - </h1>
    <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u></u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The requested resource is not available.</u>
        </p>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
            <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.62</h3>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Is there any additional step that I need to take after creating a Local Git repository.??**

## UPDATE

I deleted the project and import it from the local repository as Maven project.
In my .project file I found some changes here.

```
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
```

look at it here:

https://github.com/agrawalvikas/quickpay/commit/f38a9a36085c1bb0101fd6b8957924e71373130f

Comment: I am afraid your question is too generic and lacks code examples to show what you have done so far. What is the code that you wrote that does not behave as expected? What are the error messages that you see in the log? What REST API are you calling? There is no enough information to even attempt an answer

Comment: My code is working well. No worries about that. Question is , do I need to take any further step after I add local repository to git to make my maven project working ?

Comment: I added the code. @EvilToad

Comment: I don't understand. What is the relationship between your Java app and git? Git is source control and unrelated to app functionality.

Comment: @VikasAgrawal If you have an answer it should be an answer, not part of the question. But again--Git is orthogonal to Java and Maven.

Comment: @VikasAgrawal Those changes have absolutely nothing to do with anything remotely Git-related unless there's a really bad bug in Eclipse.

Comment: @DaveNewton look at my UPDATE.. I don't why this happened but when I saw some videos on "how to git with Eclipse" they did one thing that they deleted project and imported again to make it work. see this video.. He do it at 4:00
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptK9-CNms98

Comment: Even I found that Eclipse Luna has some bugs with git and Eclipse kelper is good. I am just exploring things as I'm very new in this. If you see the video I'd be curious to know why he would delete and import it again to  make project work.?

Comment: @VikasAgrawal Again, answers should be answers, not embedded in the question. This sounds more like some deep issue with Eclipse/the Maven plugin, or the project wasn't completely corrected in the first place. I won't be watching the video though, sorry.

Comment: It's okay. Thanks for the reply though.
I'm posting answer as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the project in the package explorer and import it again as Maven project from the directory where local repository of the main project is.

I don't know why this would work but it is working for me.
I got the reference of doing this from this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptK9-CNms98